# Azure bicep failed to download .NET

Tags: macos, azure-bicep

hopefully somebody can help me to solve this issue.
I am working on a macOS Monterey 12.0.1 and I installed visual studio code 2. Everything works fine so far, but when I open a `bicep` file. I Get this error.

```
Downloading the .NET Runtime.
Downloading .NET version(s) 5.0.11 ....... Error!
Failed to download .NET 5.0.11:
Command failed: "/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime-1.3.0/dist/install scripts/dotnet-install.sh" -InstallDir "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/5.0.11" -Version 5.0.11 -Runtime dotnet
dotnet_install: Error: Could not find `.NET Core Runtime` with version = 5.0.11
dotnet_install: Error: Refer to: https://aka.ms/dotnet-os-lifecycle for information on .NET Core support


 Error!
.NET Acquisition Failed: Installation failed: Error: Command failed: "/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime-1.3.0/dist/install scripts/dotnet-install.sh" -InstallDir "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/5.0.11" -Version 5.0.11 -Runtime dotnet
dotnet_install: Error: Could not find `.NET Core Runtime` with version = 5.0.11
dotnet_install: Error: Refer to: https://aka.ms/dotnet-os-lifecycle for information on .NET Core support
```

I am sure that .NET is installed as you can see if I run `botnet --info`

```
.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

but as I can understand, the path is totally different and I don't know if that is the main issue. I have another Mac Laptop and I am able to use bicep in VsCode without any issue.

Did this happened to anyone and might help me to solve this issue as I couldn't find any valid solution.

Comment: Have you tried this blog article?  https://rakhesh.com/azure/dotnet_install-error-could-not-find-net-core-runtime-with-version-5-0-11/